# Upgrade Path for 2sxc Module

Tags: 2sxc

We are working on a dnn upgrade and was wondering if there is a specific upgrade path we should follow for the 2sx module.

Installed version is 8.12
Target Upgrade version is 14.07.04 (Latest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that should work.
I believe any pre-8.12 would need to go to the latest 8 to continue - but the installer would show you a warning.

This was just done to ensure that newer packages don't need the big parts of older upgrade code.

See also https://docs.2sxc.org/abyss/platforms/dnn/index.html